# Form submission wont work in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I used POST method in my form to submit the value. Here is my form code:

```
<form action="{{ url('/') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="value1" value="one" />
    <input type="hidden" name="value2" value="two" />

    <input type="submit" value="SEND!" />
</form>
```

and router.php code:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});

Route::post('/', function()
{
        $data = Input::all();
        var_dump($data);
});
```

whether every time I pressed SEND button it shows the index file. When I tried commenting out the get method. Now it shows a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error. On error message it shows that request method is GET

[image]

What should I do now? Is that a bug? Or something wrong in my script?

Comment: You should probably be using RESTful controllers, it makes things so much easy. You can then have a controller specifically for your form that will handle showing the form, getting the input etc... you can use php artisan controller:make and laravel will generate the boilerplate controller for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1804.

What I have seen is that Laravel removes all trailing '/' from the URL by redirecting to the url without '/' with code 301. Your browser will be follow this redirection with a GET request instead of a new POST request.

I had the same issue when posting to any url with a trailing '/'. Why don't you process the post at another url like '/post' to see if this is really the issue?

Comment: Yes I used /date and that's working fine. Also funny thing is if I replace '/' with a space ' ', it also work.

Comment: So trailing slash only use get. That means I have to change my URL?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Laravel are you using?  Laravel v4 comes with CSRF(Cross site request forgery) protection baked in.  You need to include a hidden `_token` field by getting Laravel to generate one for you use `Form::token()` if you use `Form::open()` method instead it will add the token field for you.  Laravel will automatically look for that _token field and if it isn't found, or is not a correct token it will throw an exception.

Edit:  Check out Filters.php in your app/ directory for more info on the CSRF filter.

Comment: Yes I am using laravel 4, I added that on tag. And no csrf isn't working. I added a hidden input with _token and check before function on router, but same result.

Comment: Then it has to do with your URL.  Like Mohamed said.